# "syntax error near unexpected token `do'" in Bash script

Tags: shell

I'm writing a Bash script. When I run it, I get a syntax error I don't understand.

Here my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while [ $i -le "6" ]
 do
 j=1
 i=`expr $i +1`
 echo \
 while [ $j -le "$i" ]
   do
   echo $i
   j=`expr $j+1`
 done
done
echo \enter code here
```

Here the error:

```
./test.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
./test.sh: line 9: `do'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the backslash after `echo` really there? If so, you should remove it because it escapes the linebreak.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing if to remove the backslash from line 8, since it's an escape character (and it would escape the newline after it). In the final line, the backslash doesn't have that impact because it's followed by an `e`.

Also, in the `expr` expression, you need to surround the `+` sign with spaces. I also show a second way to increment `j`.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while [ $i -le "6" ]
 do
 j=1
 ((i++))
 echo something-else
 while [ $j -le "$i" ]
   do
   echo $i
   ((j++))
 done
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./so_test.sh
something-else
2
2
something-else
3
3
3
something-else
4
4
4
4
something-else
5
5
5
5
5
something-else
6
6
6
6
6
6
something-else
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
```

Comment: the edit changed the code for incrementing `i` that I originally posted.